# jQuery adding event handlers to eval'ed elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I've a table generated dynamically by jQuery, using

```
this.html("<table><tr><td><div>Click Me</div></td></tr></table>");
```

within the table, I've a few *divs* (my sample shows only one to keep things simple), which I want to add click event handler to. I'd like to keep html clean and use as much of jQuery power as I can, but since I'm doing an 'eval' type of things I can't quite figure out how to do that.

I know, that I can use `$("div[some attribute selector]").on("click", {}, clickHandler);`, but is it a good idea in my case?

Comment: Can you show us your `eval()` code? Using `eval()` isn't a good practice, so there might be other ways of doing it.

Comment: @JamWaffles - in here 'eval' means that we're converting 'strings to things' by calling this.htm(string).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need delegated events. To do that, simply use jQuerys `on()` method like this:

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'div', function( event ) {
    // do something
});
```

Ref.: [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

What is that? Almost all events do what we call 'bubble'. That means, if you click on a nested element, your browser looks if there is any click-event handler ascociated on that node. If so, it executes them and then the parent of that element is also asked if there is any click-event handler. This continues until either some handler `prevents` the event from further bubbling or we have reached the `document.documentElement` (html).

So, you should **change** the above `document.body` into the **closest** node relative to your dynamically added elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to do that